# How to write down the detailed balance (microreversed) amplitude

Tags: scattering, collision, s-matrix-theory

I know that time-reversal of a reaction and the detailed balance (microreversed, or reciprocal) reaction are *different*.  Textbooks on scattering theory explain how to relate the S-matrix elements of a two reactions that are related by time-reversal.

But how does the microreversed amplitude fit in (is it another element of the S-matrix), and how is it related to the non-reversed amplitude?  Is there an overall phase, and so on...?